# Lua metamethod that fires when removing an element from a table

Tags: lua

I am looking for a metamethod (or a workaround) that fires when removing an element from a lua table similar to the `__newindex` metamethod.

Ideally it would work something like the following:

```
local mytable = {}

local mt = {
  __newindex = function(t,k,v)
    rawset(t,k,v)
    -- some other functionality
  end,

  -- This does not exist
  __remove = function(t,k)
    --some functionality
  end
}

setmetatable(mytable,mt)

-- __newindex fires
mytable["key"] = value

-- __remove fires
mytable["key"] = nil
```

I have tried working with the `__gc` metamethod but that is not usable in this implementation due to the fact that the metamethod only triggers when the garbage collection cycle happens. I have no control over the garbage collection because the table (with the metamethods) is passed to a different script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible workaround - do not store actual data within table.

Let your `mytable` act as a proxy, and store actual values in some shadow table. It might be allocated along with `mytable`, or data can be stored directly in metatable (so metatable must be created per `mytable` instance).
Here's example (easily broken by writing data under metamethods' name keys, but you get an idea), data will be stored within metatable:
http://ideone.com/eCOal3

```
local mytable = {}

local mt = {}

function mt.__newindex(t,k,new_value)
    local previous_value = mt[k]
    rawset(mt,k,new_value)

    if previous_value and new_value == nil then
        print "__remove() triggered"
    end
end
mt.__index = mt

setmetatable(mytable, mt)

mytable.key = 123
print(mytable.key)

mytable.key = nil
print(mytable.key)
```

Answer (score 1):

As assigning nil fires not metamethod at all, you will have to resort to an explicit removal function that does whatever you wanted the metamethod to do and then assign nil to the table entry.